# How to remove "__main__." from the beginning of user-created exception classes in Python

Tags: python, exception, class

Is there a way to get a "prettier" exception rather than one prefaced with `__main__MyExceptionTitle`?

Example:

```
>>> class BadThings(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, msg):
...         self.msg = msg
...         return
... 
>>> class BadThings(Exception):
...     def __init__(self, msg):
...         self.msg = msg
...         return
...     def __str__(self):
...         return self.msg
... 
>>> raise BadThings("This is really, really bad")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.BadThings: This is really, really bad
```

I would like it to just say:

> BadThings: This is really, really bad

Just as if one types:

```
>>> raise Exception("This, too, is really, really bad")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: This, too, is really, really bad
```

I would like the `__main__`. gone!

Thanks,
Narnie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to remove `__main__` because that is the module name and when your exception would be in a appropriately named module, it would look beautiful not ugly  e.g. `myexceptions.BadException`

Alternatively you can catch exception and print as you wish.

But if you want the uncaught exceptions to be printed as per your wish, try to set `sys.excepthook` e.g.

```
class BadThings(Exception): pass 

import traceback
def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
    l = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(type, value, tb))
    print l

import sys
sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

raise BadThings("bad bad")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 12, in <module>
    raise BadThings("bad bad")
BadThings: bad bad
```

So in `sys.excepthook` you can modify exception, format it etc

Comment: I was just thinking from an end-user standpoint. They might not understand __main__., but I didn't know that it would print the module name, that is better, but they wouldn't understand that either. I see what you mean about catching the exceptions. I like your solution final above as it teaches me more about what is going on "behind the scenes."

Answer (score 19):

```
class MyException(Exception):
    __module__ = Exception.__module__
```

This way looks/works better than `sys.excepthook`

---

## Source Code Reference

### Python2

See `PyErr_Display`

There're two ways to bypass the module name part:

```
class A(Exception):
    __module__ = None

class B(Exception):
    __module__ = 'exceptions'
```

But if you need to play with `threading.Thread`, the first one will introduce a `TypeError`.

### Python 3

See `PyErr_WriteUnraisable`

```
class C(Exception):
    __module__ = 'builtins'
```

Comment: This is great! However, I ran into a problem when I subclassed `Exception()` in two levels of subclasses... `__module__` doesn't do anything if you put in the parent (base) Exception() sub-class... it worked perfectly when I put it in the lowest child sub-classes...

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the exception, you can format the message any way you like:

```
>>> try:
...     raise BadThings("This is really, really bad")
... except BadThings, e:
...     print e.msg
... 
This is really, really bad
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a slight modification of @Anurag's answer.

If you want to get rid of the `__main__.` AND the traceback, you can do something like this:

```
import sys
import traceback

class BadThings(Exception):
    def myexcepthook(type, value, tb):
        msg = ''.join(traceback.format_exception_only(type, value))
        print(msg)

    sys.excepthook = myexcepthook

raise BadThings("This is really, really bad")
```

Output:

```
BadThings: This is really, really bad
```

An added benefit of defining `sys.excepthook` in the exception class is that it won't override all exceptions, just `BadThings`.

Comment: *"An added benefit of defining `sys.excepthook` in the exception class is that it won't override all exceptions, just `BadThings`."* -- That's incorrect. Did you try it? Swap `raise BadThings` for `raise Exception` in the example and see what happens. The problem is that `sys` is outside the class; you just happen to be modifying it in the class body.